# Suppress text (space) output when using \glsadd{}

Tags: spacing, glossaries, glossaries-extra

I'm using the **`glossaries`** (or **`glossaries-extra`**) and am trying to add terms to the glossary silently. That is, inside my document, I occasionally want to add a term to the glossary *without* it appearing in the text output at the point where I use the command.

I tried `glsadd{<key>}`. This fulfills both criteria. But annoyingly it produces a space, when written on empty lines. Is there a package-option to prevent this or another command?

Any help would be appreciated. The following is minimal example which demonstrates the issues sufficiently.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{glossaries} % problem exists under glossaries-extra too

\newglossaryentry{term}{sort={0}, name={Term}, description={Something.}}
\newglossaryentry{here}{sort={1}, name={Here}, description={Something.}}
\newglossaryentry{is}{sort={2}, name={Is}, description={Something.}}
\newglossaryentry{more}{sort={3}, name={More}, description={Something.}}
\newglossaryentry{proof}{sort={4}, name={Proof}, description={Something.}}

\makeglossaries

\def\silentcmd#1{\setcounter{page}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \setlength{\parskip}{1\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0em}

    Here is a sentence I want to to add a term \glsadd{term} silently and that works. But then consider writing a command on an empty line.

    Between me and the last paragraph is nothing.

    \silentcmd{5}

    Between me and the last paragraph is a silent command.

    \glsadd{here}

    Between me and the last paragraph is a glsadd-command.

    \glsadd{is}

    \glsadd{more}

    \glsadd{proof}

    For clarity, between me and the last paragraph are 3 glsadd-commands.
    Is there another command to glsadd to properly silently add terms to the glossary? If not\ldots why??!
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glossaries` keeps track of on which pages the glossary entries are used. In order to this, the page on which this happens needs to be well defined, i.e. `\glsadd` has to be part of a line of text. This is why `glossaries` adds an empty `\mbox` to the document using `\@gls@adjustmode` when you call `\glsadd` in vertical mode.

You should decide to which paragraph every `\glsadd` belongs, then you won't have this problem and `glossaries` will record reasonable page numbers. For example

```
This is a paragraph with some entries at the end.
\glsadd{some}
\glsadd{entries}

\glsadd{other}
\glsadd{entries}
This is a paragraph with other entries at the beginning and something between sentences.
\glsadd{something}
This way it is always well defined where in the document you called \verb|\glsadd|.
```

---

If you don't care about page numbers (and are using the `nonumberlist` option), you can remove the feature with

```
\makeatletter
  \AtBeginDocument{\let\@gls@adjustmode\@empty}
\makeatother
```

in your preamble.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!